# ghostscript using nonlocal pdf

Tags: c#, ghostscript

Is there any way to use the ghostscript library to work with a pdf given as a byte stream, WITHOUT saving the file itself on the local machine?

I'm using C#.

Answer (score 0):

If just speed is your concern, you could try a ramdisk. Assuming you are using Windows, [here is a link](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/05/27/free-ramdisk-for-windows-vista-xp-2000-and-2003-server/) for getting a free ramdisk driver. The obvious downside: you have to install it before.

Comment: it's not about the speed. it's about the storage itself. thanks for the answer though.